# JSON encode add for each date between in SQL record

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a table in mysql which has a startdate and enddate.

An example of 1 row would be:

```
startdate -> 20121224
endate -> 20121226
title -> name
```

this would return **(OUTPUT!!!)**:

```
[{"user":"378","date":"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startdate)","title":"name","description":"6 Days","url":"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(enddate)","bmanager":"manager name","academic_year":"20120801","division":"division name","manager_id":"3"}]
```

As this record spans over 3 days i would like the JSON to output one for each date (the only differnce being the date, please see below) **I WANT THIS INSTEAD**

```
[{"user":"378","date":"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1st date)","title":"name","description":"6 Days","url":"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1st date)","bmanager":"manager name","academic_year":"20120801","division":"division name","manager_id":"3"},
{"user":"378","date":"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2nd date)","title":"name","description":"6 Days","url":"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2nd date)","bmanager":"manager name","academic_year":"20120801","division":"division name","manager_id":"3"},
{"user":"378","date":"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(3rd date)","title":"name","description":"6 Days","url":"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(3rd date)","bmanager":"manager name","academic_year":"20120801","division":"division name","manager_id":"3"},]
```

**THIS IS THE SCRIPT IM USING:**

```
$sqldata = mysql_query('
SELECT
datediff(requests.end_date, requests.start_date) as numdays,
requests.user,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requests.start_date) AS date,
requests.employee AS title, 
requests.days AS description,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requests.end_date) AS url,
business.line_manager AS bmanager,
requests.academic_year,
business.academic_year,
business.division,
line_managers.userid AS manager_id
FROM requests 
INNER JOIN holiday_entitlement_business_manual AS business ON requests.user=business.userid AND requests.academic_year=business.academic_year
INNER JOIN line_managers ON business.line_manager=line_managers.name
WHERE requests.approved = 1
');

$posts = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata))
{
    $row['date'] = $row['date'].'000';
    $row['url'] = $row['url'].'000';
    $posts[] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result($sqldata);
die(json_encode($posts));
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Please explain what this script is not doing that you need it to do.

Comment: What's the question here? What does your script output?  What should it output?  Do you get any errors?  What's the problem here?

Comment: it is all in the question! the script output is there along with the desired output. No errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace your code by the following:

```
$sqldata = mysql_query('
SELECT
requests.start_date as startdate,
datediff(requests.end_date, requests.start_date) as numdays,
requests.user,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requests.start_date) AS date,
requests.employee AS title, 
requests.days AS description,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requests.end_date) AS url,
business.line_manager AS bmanager,
requests.academic_year,
business.academic_year,
business.division,
line_managers.userid AS manager_id
FROM requests 
INNER JOIN holiday_entitlement_business_manual AS business ON requests.user=business.userid AND requests.academic_year=business.academic_year
INNER JOIN line_managers ON business.line_manager=line_managers.name
WHERE requests.approved = 1
');

$posts = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata))
{
   $startDate = $row['startdate'];
   unset($array['startdate']);
   $dayDiff = $row['numdays'];
   $row['date'] = $row['date'].'000';
   $row['url'] = $row['url'].'000';
   for($i = 0; $i <= $dayDiff; $i++)
   {
      $row['date'] = ...; // Do here the date parsing and add $i to the days
      $posts[] = $row;
   }

}
mysql_free_result($sqldata);
die(json_encode($posts));
```

These functions [dateparse()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) and [mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) will probably help you with the date manipulation.

Comment: you did beat me on timing. +1'd ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I got your point. This could give you a starting point.
Basically, you need to fetch all rows, and then create one record for every day you wish to take into account.

```
 $sqldata = mysql_query('
    SELECT
    datediff(requests.end_date, requests.start_date) as numdays,
    requests.user,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requests.start_date) AS date,
    requests.employee AS title, 
    requests.days AS description,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requests.end_date) AS url,
    business.line_manager AS bmanager,
    requests.academic_year,
    business.academic_year,
    business.division,
    line_managers.userid AS manager_id
    FROM requests 
    INNER JOIN holiday_entitlement_business_manual AS business ON requests.user=business.userid AND requests.academic_year=business.academic_year
    INNER JOIN line_managers ON business.line_manager=line_managers.name
    WHERE requests.approved = 1
    ');

$posts = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata))
{
    $row['date'] = $row['date'];
    $row['url'] = $row['url'];
    for($x = $row['date']; $x < $row['url']; $x+= 86400) {
          // where 86400 makes you advancing by a day in secs
          $row['date'] = $x;
          $row['url'] = $x;
          $posts[] = $row;
    }
    $posts[] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result($sqldata);
die(json_encode($posts));
```